# Setting the Owner property on a modal dialog in WPF/MVVM using a Func

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm looking to solve the problem of setting the `Owner` property on modal dialogs in WPF, while using IoC and MVVM patterns. I've seen (and written) all sorts of hacks.

To illustrate the problem, here's a naive example of a window with a viewmodel containing an ICommand which prompts the user. It works by having the view set `vm.Owner = this`, and then the viewmodel using `Owner` later in a MessageBox when the command is called.

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MyWindowViewModel vm;

    public MyWindow(MyWindowViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = vm;
        vm.Owner = this;
    }
}

public class MyWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly RelayCommand<object> fooCommand;

    public ICommand FooCommand => fooCommand;
    public Window Owner { get; set; }

    public MyWindowViewModel()
    {
        fooCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(OnFooCommand);
    }

    private void OnFooCommand(object obj)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show(Owner, "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but the ViewModel is doing View-related things like opening message boxes, and knowing who owns it.

Here's an example that abstracts the dialog into a Func, which is set in the constructor of the Window.

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MyWindowViewModel vm;

    public MyWindow(MyWindowViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = vm;
        vm.OkCancelBox = OkCancelBox;
    }

    private MessageBoxResult OkCancelBox(string text)
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(this, text, "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question);
    }
}

public class MyWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly RelayCommand<object> fooCommand;

    public ICommand FooCommand => fooCommand;
    public Func<string, MessageBoxResult> OkCancelBox { get; set; } = s => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public MyWindowViewModel()
    {
        fooCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(OnFooCommand);
    }

    private void OnFooCommand(object obj)
    {
        if (OkCancelBox("Are you sure?") == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This feels better, now my ViewModel calls OkCancelBox and gets back a MessageBoxResult, without knowing anything about the View. If you "forget" to set OkCancelBox, you'll get a NotImplementedException. In a test, I can trivially set the Func to simulate the user clicking "OK":

```
vm.OkCancelBox = s => MessageBoxResult.OK;
```

Still, I'm not sure I like it.

There are other solutions like passing in (or service-locating) an IMessageBoxService, but I don't fully understand how you can specify the owner of a dialog without the ViewModel knowing who owns it.

Any thoughts on my implementation using `Func<string, MessageBoxResult>`?